# Scale bar labels and stretch on maps based on spatial mean and deviation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to map data a certain way for a better data visualization: I wish Scale bar labels and the stretch applied to colors to be based on the spatial mean value plus or minus two standard deviations. I saw that in a paper but I am not sure how best to do that. I have tried the script below but get the error message:

> Error in continuous_scale("fill", "gradient", seq_gradient_pal(low,
>   high,  : 
>         unused arguments (mid = "white", midpoint = 500)

```
require(ggplot2)
require(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)

mean_val <- mean(Df$layer , na.rm=T)
sd_val<- sd(Df$layer , na.rm=T)
Df <- Df[Df$layer < mean_val+2*sd_val,]
Df <- Df[Df$layer > mean_val -2*sd_val,]

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = wrld_simpl, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
               colour = "black", fill = "grey") 
p <- p + geom_raster(data = Df , aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer))
p <- p + coord_equal() +  theme_bw()  +labs(x="", y="") 
p <- p + scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", mid="white", high = "green", midpoint=mean_val)
p
```

Df is here https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/index.php/s/ywvcxkUaEpkEd9N (edu link). Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please provide the data for a reproducible example in _the question itself_. Links may die in the future, and we would like this question to remain reproducible for others later. You probably should to use `coord_map` not `coord_fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scale_fill_gradient2` instead of `scale_fill_gradient` function.